# Slow wired internet speed Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: internet

Just switched from WinXP to Ubuntu 13.10 and have extremely low net speed compared to what I had, (600kbs) to now (50kbs). I installed all the updates. No idea what to do.

Comment: It's not software related (I'm right now downloading with over 800KB/s). Something is wrong with your hardware or your speed testing method.

Comment: ..like GabrielF writes, if you experience the downloads being slower, you might want to troubleshoot your network hardware; or you might just have been confused with the speed units _(KBytes/s and Kbits/s: 1KBps = 8Kbps; note the case of "B")_ presented to you by the n/w speed test utility.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ifconfig`.

There should be two different txqueuelen values, 1 paragraph then another paragraph

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 10000&&sudo ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 10000
```

---

your eth0 and eth1 may be different than those listed

Increasing The txqueuelen

Increase the txqueuelength parameter to a value between 1000 and 20000 per interface:

```
ifconfig ${interface} txqueuelen ${size}
ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 10000
ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 5000
```